# iframe showing blank on load in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I have a simple php page that should show html in a frame. When I open it in Firefox it works perfectly. When I open it in Crome it shows up blank (with vertical scroll bars) and only when I scroll it (either by mouse wheel or by clicking up/down arrows on the scroll bars) or when I scroll the page down so that I cannot see the frame and then back up - only then I can normally see the text.
I have even tried substituting it with a normal frame but then it does not show at all.

```
<iframe id="first" src="01001.htm#20" width="600" height="100"></iframe>
```

Thanks.

edit:

PHP:

```
<html>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/20/profile">
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="favicon.png">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Vedrije jutro</title>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:900px">
    <div id="header">
        <div><span style="font: bold 30pt arial">Vedrije jutro</span><span style="margin-left:120px; font: 20px arial">Svakodnevno proučavanje Svetog Pisma korak po korak</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="toolbar">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="jutarnji">
                <h3>Jutarnji stih:</h3>
                <div><b>Jovan 6:35 - "Sigurni u Isusovim rukama: Jedini izvor istine"</b></div>
                <iframe id="first" src="01001.htm#20" width="600" height="100"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="pouka">
                <h3>Biblijska pouka:</h3>
                <iframe id="pouka" src="pouke/2-2012.pdf#page=95" width="640" height="600" frameborder="0" style="padding:0"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="redom">
            </div>
            <div id="vecernje">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTM:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<TITLE>1 Mojsijeva, glava 1</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="biblija.css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="layer1.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY OnLoad="namosw_init_float_layers('layer1', 6);">
<div id="layer1" style="width:320px; height:26px; position:absolute; left:10px; top:980px; z-index:1; ">

    <pre>1 Mojsijeva, glava 1   <OBJECT
  id=shortcut
  type="application/x-oleobject"
  classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11">
  <PARAM name="Command" value="ShortCut">
  <PARAM name="Button" value="Bitmap:note.bmp">
  <PARAM name="Item1" value="wordpad,wordpad.exe,beleske/sz/1Mojsijeva/01.pog">
  </OBJECT></pre>




</div>








<FONT SIZE=3>
<p><a name="1"></A><sup>1</sup> U početku stvori Bog nebo i zemlju.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV038.HTM#4">Jov 38:4</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="23ISA044.HTM#24">Isa. 44:24</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="23ISA045.HTM#18">Isa. 45:18</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="43JVN001.HTM#1">Jn. 1:1</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="43JVN001.HTM#3">Jn. 1:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="45RIM001.HTM#20">Rim. 1:20</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="51KOL001.HTM#16">Kol. 1:16</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="58JEV001.HTM#10">Jev. 1:10</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="58JEV011.HTM#3">Jev. 11:3</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="2"></A><sup>2</sup> A zemlja beše bez obličja i pusta, i beše tama nad bezdanom; i duh Božji dizaše se nad vodom.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="23ISA040.HTM#12">Isa. 40:12</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="24JER004.HTM#23">Jer. 4:23</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="3"></A><sup>3</sup> I reče Bog: Neka bude svetlost. I bi svetlost.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA033.HTM#9">Ps. 33:9</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="4"></A><sup>4</sup> I vide Bog svetlost da je dobra; i rastavi Bog svetlost od tame.</P>
<p><a name="5"></A><sup>5</sup> I svetlost nazva Bog dan, a tamu nazva noć. I bi veče i bi jutro, dan prvi.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV038.HTM#12">Jov 38:12</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA074.HTM#16">Ps. 74:16</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="6"></A><sup>6</sup> Potom reče Bog: Neka bude svod posred vode, da rastavlja vodu od vode.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV037.HTM#18">Jov 37:18</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA033.HTM#6">Ps. 33:6</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="24JER010.HTM#12">Jer. 10:12</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="7"></A><sup>7</sup> I stvori Bog svod, i rastavi vodu pod svodom od vode nad svodom; i bi tako.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA148.HTM#4">Ps. 148:4</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="8"></A><sup>8</sup> A svod nazva Bog nebo. I bi veče i bi jutro, dan drugi.</P>
<p><a name="9"></A><sup>9</sup> Potom reče Bog: Neka se sabere voda što je pod nebom na jedno mesto, i neka se pokaže suvo. I bi tako.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV026.HTM#10">Jov 26:10</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="18JOV038.HTM#8">Jov 38:8</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="18JOV038.HTM#10">Jov 38:10</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA095.HTM#5">Ps. 95:5</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="10"></A><sup>10</sup> I suvo nazva Bog zemlja, a zborišta vodena nazva mora; i vide Bog da je dobro.</P>
<p><a name="11"></A><sup>11</sup> Opet reče Bog: Neka pusti zemlja iz sebe travu, bilje, što nosi seme, i drvo rodno, koje rađa rod po svojim vrstama, u kome će biti seme njegovo na zemlji. I bi tako.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="40MAT007.HTM#17">Mt. 7:17</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="42LUK006.HTM#4">Lk. 6:4</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="58JEV006.HTM#7">Jev. 6:7</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="12"></A><sup>12</sup> I pusti zemlja iz sebe travu, bilje, što nosi seme po svojim vrstama, i drvo, koje rađa rod, u kome je seme njegovo po njegovim vrstama. I vide Bog da je dobro.</P>
<p><a name="13"></A><sup>13</sup> I bi veče i bi jutro, dan treći.</P>
<p><a name="14"></A><sup>14</sup> Potom reče Bog: Neka budu videla na svodu nebeskom, da dele dan i noć, da budu znaci vremenima i danima i godinama;<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="055MO004.HTM#19">5 Moj. 4:19</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="18JOV025.HTM#3">Jov 25:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="18JOV025.HTM#5">Jov 25:5</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA074.HTM#16">Ps. 74:16</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA136.HTM#7">Ps. 136:7</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="15"></A><sup>15</sup> I neka svetle na svodu nebeskom, da obasjavaju zemlju. I bi tako.</P>
<p><a name="16"></A><sup>16</sup> I stvori Bog dva videla velika: videlo veće da upravlja danom, i videlo manje da upravlja noću, i zvezde.</P>
<p><a name="17"></A><sup>17</sup> I postavi ih Bog na svodu nebeskom da obasjavaju zemlju.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA008.HTM#1">Ps. 8:1</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="18"></A><sup>18</sup> I da upravljaju danom i noću, i da dele svetlost od tame. I vide Bog da je dobro.</P>
<p><a name="19"></A><sup>19</sup> I bi veče i bi jutro, dan četvrti.</P>
<p><a name="20"></A><sup>20</sup> Potom reče Bog: Neka vrve po vodi žive duše, i ptice neka lete iznad zemlje pod svod nebeski.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA104.HTM#24">Ps. 104:24</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="21"></A><sup>21</sup> I stvori Bog kitove velike i sve žive duše što se miču, što provrveše po vodi po vrstama svojim, i sve ptice krilate po vrstama njihovim. I vide Bog da je dobro;</P>
<p><a name="22"></A><sup>22</sup> I blagoslovi ih Bog govoreći: Rađajte se i množite se, i napunite vodu po morima, i ptice neka se množe na zemlji.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="011MO008.HTM#17">1 Moj. 8:17</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="24JER029.HTM#6">Jer. 29:6</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="23"></A><sup>23</sup> I bi veče i bi jutro, dan peti.</P>
<p><a name="24"></A><sup>24</sup> Potom reče Bog: Neka zemlja pusti iz sebe duše žive po vrstama njihovim, stoku i sitne životinje i zveri zemaljske po vrstama njihovim. I bi tako.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA033.HTM#9">Ps. 33:9</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="25"></A><sup>25</sup> I stvori Bog zveri zemaljske po vrstama njihovim, i stoku po vrstama njenim, i sve sitne životinje na zemlji po vrstama njihovim. I vide Bog da je dobro.</P>
<p><a name="26"></A><sup>26</sup> Potom reče Bog: Da načinimo čoveka po svom obličju, kao što smo mi, koji će biti gospodar od riba morskih i od ptica nebeskih i od stoke i od cele zemlje i od svih životinja što se miču po zemlji.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV020.HTM#4">Jov 20:4</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA008.HTM#6">Ps. 8:6</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA100.HTM#3">Ps. 100:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="49EFE004.HTM#24">Ef. 4:24</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="59JAK003.HTM#9">Jak. 3:9</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="27"></A><sup>27</sup> I stvori Bog čoveka po obličju svom, po obličju Božjem stvori ga; muško i žensko stvori ih.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="21PRO007.HTM#29">Prop. 7:29</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="39MAL002.HTM#15">Mal. 2:15</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="40MAT019.HTM#4">Mt. 19:4</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="41MAR010.HTM#6">Mk. 10:6</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="461KO011.HTM#7">1 Kor. 11:7</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="51KOL003.HTM#10">Kol. 3:10</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="28"></A><sup>28</sup> I blagoslovi ih Bog, i reče im Bog: Rađajte se i množite se, i napunite zemlju, i vladajte njom, i budite gospodari od riba morskih i od ptica nebeskih i od svih zveri što se miče po zemlji.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="011MO006.HTM#1">1 Moj. 6:1</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="011MO009.HTM#1">1 Moj. 9:1</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="011MO009.HTM#7">1 Moj. 9:7</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="011MO035.HTM#11">1 Moj. 35:11</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="033MO026.HTM#9">3 Moj. 26:9</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA127.HTM#3">Ps. 127:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA128.HTM#3">Ps. 128:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="23ISA045.HTM#18">Isa. 45:18</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="541TI004.HTM#3">1 Tim. 4:3</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="29"></A><sup>29</sup> I još reče Bog: Evo, dao sam vam sve bilje što nosi seme po svoj zemlji, i sva drveta rodna koja nose seme; to će vam biti za hranu.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV036.HTM#31">Jov 36:31</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA136.HTM#25">Ps. 136:25</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA146.HTM#7">Ps. 146:7</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="44DEL014.HTM#17">Dela 14:17</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="30"></A><sup>30</sup> A svim zverima zemaljskim i svim pticama nebeskim i svemu što se miče na zemlji i u čemu ima duša živa, dao sam svu travu da jedu. I bi tako.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="18JOV039.HTM#3">Jov 39:3</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA145.HTM#15">Ps. 145:15</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="19PSA147.HTM#9">Ps. 147:9</A></small></div></P>
<p><a name="31"></A><sup>31</sup> Tada pogleda Bog sve što je stvorio, i gle, dobro beše veoma. I bi veče i bi jutro, dan šesti.<BR>
<div align="right"><small><A HREF="19PSA104.HTM#24">Ps. 104:24</A><EM>, </EM><A HREF="541TI004.HTM#4">1 Tim. 4:4</A></small></div></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<CENTER><IMG SRC="linija.gif"></P>
<P><div align="center"></P>
<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0>
<TR><TD VALIGN="MIDDLE">
<TD VALIGN="TOP">
<P><A HREF="#top"><IMG SRC="vrh.gif" ALIGN=CENTER BORDER=0 ALT="Vrh stranice"></A></TD>
<TD VALIGN="MIDDLE">
<P><A HREF="011MO002.HTM"><IMG SRC="s_glava.gif" ALIGN=RIGHT BORDER=0 ALT="Sledeca glava"></A></TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD VALIGN="MIDDLE">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="MIDDLE">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="MIDDLE">
<P><A HREF="022MO001.HTM"><IMG SRC="s_knjiga.gif" ALIGN=RIGHT BORDER=0 ALT="Sledeca knjiga"></A></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE><p>&nbsp;</p>

<P></P></BODY>
</HTML>
```

Does this help?

Comment: post the code of the `01001.htm`